# Android Dialog doesn't disappear completely when User tries to go back

Tags: android, android-activity, android-dialog

I created a dialog activity using the following snippet. I'm using a translucent theme for this activity.So it looks neat.

```
public class DialogActivity extends Activity {
AlertDialog alertDialog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Title");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Body");
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    aleratDialog.setButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            DialogActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(alertDialog!=null) {alertDialog.dismiss();}
    super.onPause();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if(alertDialog!=null) {alertDialog.dismiss();}
    super.onStop();

}
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        finish();
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}


}
```

I am having trouble when the user clicks on the Back button. The activity still stays on foreground when the user does that. I tried overriding the `onKeyDown` method to call `finish()` when the user tries to go back but this didn't help.

Note: The onBackPressed or onKeyDown methods are not invoked when I press back for the first time.(The ActionBar stays) I have to press it a second time to get there and then the activity actually disappears

I think this has got something to do with my Manifest entry

```
<activity
        android:name=".DialogActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:noHistory="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" />
```

Comment: try after registering DialogActivity Activity in manifest as : `<activity android:name=".DialogActivity" android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:noHistory="true" />`

Comment: tried that but still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is create a dialog (the DialogActivity), and from it open another dialog with the alert builder. So you get 2 dialogs, and clicking back removes the alert dialog, but not the DialogActivity. 
Why do you need the DialogActivity? Why not open the alert from the calling activity ?

Comment: thanks :-) I'm trying to open this from a `Notification`.  So I have wrapped the AlertDialog in an Activity so that I can start it with an `Intent`

Comment: In that case, you need to close your activity when the alert is closed. add onDismissListener to teh alert, and in it, finish() the activity

Answer (score 1):

You can use EventBus to listen DialogActivity events from another Activities. Or, you can implement inteface to listen.

EventBus(GreenRobot) examples:

https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

https://greenrobot.github.io/EventBus/

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-use-the-eventbus-library--cms-22694

Answer (score 0):

As you are calling your Dialog in onCreate(), the dialog will be on foreground.

So try to finish the dialog onBackPressed in onKeyDown Method.

Comment: `onBackPressed` on `onKeyDown` is not invoked on the user presses back button for the first time. Updated the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(alertDialog!=null) 
    alertDialog.dismiss();
    DialogActivity.this.finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

`android:launchMode="singleInstance"`

to

`android:launchMode="singleTask"`
or 
`android:launchMode="singleTop"`

Comment: When posting an answer, you should also provide some description of the solution you are proposing.

Comment: I think my answer is so clean. it isn't?
in MANIFEST file there you declare the activity do what i Say above!